# Grails withForm causing error

Tags: grails

I'm running into an issue using the code below. I'm getting an error when I add the invalidToken handler. I'm using grails V 2.3.4

```
 withForm {
       // ready to go
    }.invalidToken {
       // bad submit
    }
```

> blaaaa/blaaa/controller.groovy: 123: [Static type checking] - Cannot
>   find matching method
>   java.lang.Object#invalidToken(groovy.lang.Closure). Please check if
>   the declared type is right and if the method exists.  @ line 123,
>   column 9.
>              withForm {
>              ^

Comment: You are going to need to include much more of your controller code for us to help you identify the issue. This snippet alone lacks the details of the method it's being used within, or the class your controller is perhaps extending, and so forth.

Comment: Are you using @CompileStatic? Does it work if you don't?

Comment: Yes the file is using CompileStatic. It works if I remove that. I didn't write the code in the controller so not sure if removing CompileStatic will cause other issues. Is there a way to use it with CompileStatic

Comment: The purpose of `@GrailsCompileStatic` is to provide static type checking similar to `@CompileStatic` but be Grails aware and be able to handle Grails specific interactions which `@CompileStatic` is not aware of.  If you file a feature request at https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS we can improve `@GrailsCompileStatic` to be able to deal with this situation.

Comment: Actually, we can probably fix this to work even with `@CompileStatic`.  In any case, filing a JIRA will help affect that necessary change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, using `@CompileStatic` can cause dynamic code to fail, so you need to rework some code to be compatible. However there is a lot of functionality in Grails that isn't compatible with `@CompileStatic` as it's a relatively new feature; it's only been available to use in Grails since the 2.2 release which was the first to use Groovy 2.0.

So you'll have to rework that `withForm` block to be non-dynamic. I haven't looked at the underlying code recently but my guess is you can do it, but it will be ugly and you'll wish you hadn't. Use `@CompileStatic` where it makes sense (and it where it makes a difference; the performance difference for this block of code with and without it will likely be a few milliseconds).

I haven't worked with `@CompileStatic` enough to be sure, but I'm pretty confident that you can always remove the annotation and the code will work; you will then have redundant casts and non-dynamic code, but it's still perfectly valid Groovy.